# restar valores de un array y sumar otro valor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este array:

```
var distanciaCentroUltimo = [790,850];
var tamaño = 2455;
```

por medio de un for, ¿cómo hago para que me quede lo siguiente?

> 2455-790-850 = 815

Comment: Según el título de la pregunta, dice **restar valores de un array**, pero en el resultado esperado parece como si sumases (faltan 5 para 4100). ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente?

Comment: Esta mal desde que pones tu pregunta, 2455-790-850 = 4100? WTF?.

Comment: al parecer el 2455 es negativo y como dice @Gustavo faltan 5 para -4100, ordena tus ideas y tal vez asi podamos ayudarte.

Comment: `function restar(){var i=0;for(i=0;i<2455-790-850;i++){};return i}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejemplo de como leer secuencialmente un **arrays** a través de un `for`:

```js
var distanciaCentroUltimo = [790,850];
var tamaño = 2455;

for ( n in distanciaCentroUltimo) {
    tamaño -= parseInt(distanciaCentroUltimo[n]);
};

console.log(tamaño);
```

El resultado es 815 y no 4100

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, disculpe que no era sumar si no restar.